# Select min from subgroup pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I get such table via following query:

```py
df_netflix.groupby(by=['year_added','quarter_added'])['quarter_added'].count()
```

```
year_added  quarter_added
2008        Q1                 2
2009        Q4                 2
2010        Q4                 1
2011        Q3                 1
            Q4                12
2012        Q1                 1
            Q4                 2
2013        Q1                 1
            Q3                 3
            Q4                 7
2014        Q1                 4
            Q2                 3
            Q3                 3
            Q4                15
2015        Q1                10
            Q2                12
            Q3                17
            Q4                49
2016        Q1                77
            Q2                41
            Q3               118
            Q4               207
2017        Q1               296
            Q2               190
            Q3               314
            Q4               425
2018        Q1               393
            Q2               196
            Q3               453
            Q4               643
2019        Q1               500
            Q2               346
            Q3               450
            Q4               857
2020        Q1               497
            Q2               355
            Q3               478
            Q4               679
2021        Q1               117
```

Would you suggest any idea how to select quartal for each year where its quantity is min or max.
For the instance above:

```
year_added  quarter_min
2008        Q1                 
2009        Q4                 
2010        Q4                 
2011        Q3
2012        Q1
2013        Q1
2014        Q2
2015        Q1                
2016        Q2                
2017        Q2               
2018        Q2               
2019        Q2               
2020        Q2               
2021        Q1
```

The scrape of the original table looks like

|  | year_added | day_added | month_added | quarter_added | num_of_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 | 14 | August | Q3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2016 | 23 | December | Q4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2018 | 20 | December | Q4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2017 | 16 | November | Q4 | 3 |
| 4 | 2020 | 1 | January | Q1 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below for your grouped object.

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
grouped.columns = ['count']
grouped = grouped.reset_index()
grouped.iloc[grouped .groupby('year_added').idxmin()['count']]
```

Comment: Much appreciate!